# Virtual interface between monitor/driver and their BFM ??? What they are actually, can someone explain?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I was reading UVM cookbook and I got confused about virtual interface connection in between monitor, driver and their BFM. Does it mean there could be multiple driver or monitor, or this is independent of interfacing that does not know either its monitor or driver. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `virtual` is re-used a number of times in SystemVerilog. The interface is *virtual* in the sense that its hierarchical path is set at runtime by passing it through a variable. All other connections in Verilog/SystemVerilog are fixed paths.

This does indeed allow you to have multiple instances of the same driver code connect to multiple interface instances. It also helps in block-to-system reuse so you can change the hierarchical path as the interface gets deeper into your system level.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog was not created as a programming langue, more over, it was not suitable for object oriented programming. On the other hand, System verilog test bench language was created as an object oriented programming language.

One of the issues is to semantically connect HDL verilog with TB. All verilog HDL/RTL objects are statically compiled and cannot be manipulated dynamically (which is needed at TB). You cannot get pointers to modules, variables, ... (well except through some back-door PLI mechanism).

So, System verilog came up with the `interface` construct, which was intended as a connectivity object in RTL world. It is similar to a `module` in a sense, that it is a compile-time static object. But, SV also added a trick, which allows you to have a reference to an `interface`. The trick is called `virtual interface`.

From the point of view of a programmer, you can think of it as a reference, or a pointer to the static interface object. This gives you an ability to pass this reference to different TB class, or create multiple references tot he same interface.

Here is a schematic example:

```
class Transaction;
   virtual dut_if trans; // <<< virtual interface
   function new(virtual dut_if t);
      trans = t; // <<<< assign it to trans
   endfunction // new
endclass // Transaction

// definition of the interface
interface  dut_if import trans_pkg::*;
    (input trans_t trans);
endinterface

// instantiate the interface in module 'rtl'
bind rtl dut_if dut_if(data);

program tb;
   // pass it to the constructor as a virtual interface pointer.
   Transaction trans1 = new (rtl.dut_if);
   Transaction trans2 = new (rtl.dut_if);
endprogram // tb
```